# react testing library: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, chart.js, react-testing-library

I have this component, which uses [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2) to render a `Doughnut` chart:

```
const CompliancyChart = ({data}): JSX.Element => {
...
   return (
     <ChartStyled>
          {chartPlugins && chartData && (
            <Doughnut
              aria-label="Compliancy Chart"
              data={chartData}
              options={chartOptions}
              plugins={chartPlugins}
            />
          )}
        </ChartStyled>
    );
};
```

And I have a test file for this component which has this assertion:

```
describe('Chart component', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  test('should render without errors', async () => {
    render(<CompliancyChart data={mockCompliancyChartData} />, {});
    const compliancyChart = await screen.findByRole('img', {
      name: 'Compliancy Chart',
    });
    expect(compliancyChart).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

This test is working fine, but I keep getting this error in the test console:

```
Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
```

The only solution I could find online is to use:

```
jest.mock('react-chartjs-2', () => ({
      Doughnut: () => null,
    }))
```

Which in this case my test fails, since I can't test against `canvas` inside the screen container: (https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/155#issuecomment-821322545)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It will be easier if you show the full code even if not full code for `CompliancyChart` component, then at least `chartOptions` and `chartPlugins`.

Comment: @VijayKumar Actually the error is not related to the chart plugins neither options, even if left the chart with original options and with no plugins, I still get that error

Comment: Could you please provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 7):

Since `Jest` uses `jsdom`, there are some browser APIs that are not available on this environment. Its probably you are getting this error

> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

because [HTMLCanvasElement.getContext()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) is not present.

You can get rid of that error by installing `canvas` as dev dependency. Jsdom includes support for using this library if it is included as a dependency in your project. See [canvas-support](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#canvas-support)

`npm i canvas --save-dev`

If you get an error related to `ResizeObserver`, in that case you can mock it and your test will run fine.

```
window.ResizeObserver = function () {
  return {
    observe: jest.fn(),
    unobserve: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn(),
  };
};
```

Comment: Only the final answer here worked for me: https://github.com/ZeeCoder/use-resize-observer/issues/40